# Missing Field or method Signature Scheme in autocert on arm

Tags: linux, go, raspberry-pi, arm, glide-golang

I am writing a program in go which makes an HTTP request to different server and reads the response. The program works absolutely fine on Windows/Mac but when I run the program on ARM based Rasp Pi 3 with Rasbian OS, it fails.

Every-time I try to build the code it throws this error, could any suggest what I am doing wrong here?

```
# golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:301: hello.SupportedProtos undefined (type *tls.ClientHelloInfo has no field or method SupportedProtos)
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:311: hello.SignatureSchemes undefined (type *tls.ClientHelloInfo has no field or method SignatureSchemes)
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:314: hello.SignatureSchemes undefined (type *tls.ClientHelloInfo has no field or method SignatureSchemes)
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:315: undefined: tls.SignatureScheme
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:317: undefined: tls.ECDSAWithP256AndSHA256
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:318: undefined: tls.ECDSAWithP384AndSHA384
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:318: undefined: tls.ECDSAWithP521AndSHA512
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:344: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
../../go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert/autocert.go:347: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
```

Thanks in advance for your support, please do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What version of go do you have installed on your raspberry?

Comment: @mkopriva Go Version: go 1.7.4 linux/arm and Rasbian OS: Rasbian 4.14.71-v7+

Comment: Some of those fields where added in 1.8 i believe, so the `autocert` package is out of sync with the std lib. Upgrade Go.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#crypto_tls

Comment: @mkopriva I used the latest release only using this command, "sudo snap install go --classic".

Not sure why its installing 1.7.4, maybe that's the latest release on ARM?

Comment: @mkopriva that was the issue update my GO to 1.11 and now everything works, thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with snapd so I'm not sure how it determines the version but this gif suggests that the version be specified with the channel option https://snapcraft.io/go. I'm glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the same Go version as the other platforms. Some features may have been added in a newer version.